# Run more of one command in ShellExecute function (C++)

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to run the following lines:

```
hRet = ShellExecute(HWND_DESKTOP,
                    L"open",
               (*)  L"C:\\...\\wmplayer.exe  C:\\...\\.mp4",       
                    NULL, 
                    NULL,
                    SW_SHOW);
```

But the file(.mp4) doesn't open, maybe because I give the two pathes in one parameter.
I tried also to run the following:

```
(*)  L"\"C:\\...\\wmplayer.exe\"  \"C:\\...\\.mp4\""
```

And:

```
(*)  L"C:\\...\\wmplayer.exe\"  \"C:\\...\\.mp4"
```

But to no avail, can you please assist??
Thanks...!

Comment: Did you escape the backslashes `\\`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation I'd say the call should be

```
hRet = ShellExecute(HWND_DESKTOP,
                    L"open",
                    L"C:\\...\\wmplayer.exe",
                    L"C:\\...\\.mp4",       
                    NULL,
                    SW_SHOW);
```

The documentation says:

> lpParameters [in, optional] Type: LPCTSTR If lpFile specifies an
>   executable file, this parameter is a pointer to a null-terminated
>   string that specifies the parameters to be passed to the application.
>   The format of this string is determined by the verb that is to be
>   invoked. If lpFile specifies a document file, lpParameters should be
>   NULL.

so you could pass directly the `.mp4` file as the `lpFile` parameter and leave this `NULL` (but the default player would be used) or you must pass the player name as file and the movie name as parameter.

Comment: @Jongware: TL DR RTFM ... :-) ... but indeed sometimes windows API are quite verbose to use and they take a lot of parameters that are needed only in 1% of the cases. Too bad for them C didn't have keyword parameters when they designed the API.